# Trying to learn For loops the right way

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I've been teaching my self Node.JS recently, and its been fun. However I've hit a road block that is really killing me here. I've come to realize that I can't wrap my head around For loops in JS. Whenever I've gone to use for loops I end up just using jquery $.each() to spare my head. Well I can't rely on .each for what I'm attempting and I'm stuck trying to wrap my head around For loops. Here is what I'm working with.

Just for some context, I've been playing around with websockets in node.js. Its a lot of fun! I started with the standard ChatApp that you find everywhere, and now I'm attempting to build a multiplayer Tic-Tac-Toe game. When a player clicks on the grid, the grid choice is stored in a list inside the player object on the node.js websocket server.

The last thing I'm trying to do is compare the list of picked board nodes to a master list of possible tic-tac-toe solutions:

```
        //i'm sure this can be formatted better....
             var solutions = {
                'vert':{
                    1:[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]],
                    2:[[1,0],[1,1],[2,1]],
                    3:[[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]
                },
                'hor':{
                    1:[[0,0],[1,0],[2,0]],
                    2:[[0,1],[1,1],[2,1]],
                    3:[[0,2],[1,2],[2,2]]
                },
                'diag':{
                    1:[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]],
                    2:[[2,0],[1,1],[0,2]]
                }
            };

    // player selected grid coordinates
            var player1 = {
                'picked':[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]]
            };

// the big dumb function that I hate. 
function winCondition(solutions){
    var win = '';
    console.log('-------------------------------------------------------');
    if(win === ''){
        $.each(solutions, function(index, solution){
            $.each(solution, function(index, winCon){
                console.log('testing Win Condition ' + index,winCon);
                matches = 0;
                if(matches !== 3){
                    console.log('current match value = ' + matches);
                    $.each(winCon, function(index, gridSlot){
                        console.log('Testing ' + index,gridSlot);
                        $.each(player1.picked, function(index,gridChoice){
                            console.log('does '+ gridSlot + ' = ' + gridChoice);
                            if(gridSlot[0] == gridChoice[0] && gridSlot[1] == gridChoice[1]){
                                matches = matches + 1;
                                console.log('match! ' + matches + '/3 left');
                                if(matches == 3){
                                    win = true;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
    if (win === true){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tested this in codepen for a while and it seems to work as I want, except for the lack of .each serverside!

So how can I achieve the same results... every time I look at a for loop example my brain turns up side down. I'm sure I'm over complicating this whole matter but I've been plugging away at this for a few hours now and I think I blew a resister somewhere in my brain.

Comment: It looks like you are using the same `index` variable for all $.each which is overshadowing earlier ones. Have a distinct variable for each loop and give it a try!

Comment: What is it exactly that gives you the biggest problem in understanding for loops.

Comment: @DubemEnyekwe I think its where I'm coming from. I know a fair amount of Python and Powershell, and in both languages loops can be fairly simple looking. in python, to iterate over an array its as simple as 'for i in list => do stuff' but when I look up loops for JS it all looks like this 'for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) => do stuff' There is just a lot going on and it doesn't help me when I start diving a little deeper with nested arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, as a best practice you [shouldn't be using a for...in loop on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in), which can get you into trouble.  A [regular for loop is fine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), but for your situation I would recommend using [the `.forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on the arrays themselves, like so:

```
var array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

array.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    console.log(element, index, array);
}
```

This is a very similar method to jQuery's `.each()`, which should make the transition more straightforward.

Comment: You should specify that one shouldn't use a `for*..in*` loop over arrays. A classic for loop over the array indices is perfectly fine.

Comment: Interesting. I feel like I tried this, but maybe I didn't. I'll take another crack at it with forEach.

Comment: @ajp15243 Excellent point.  I've edited the question to be more clear.  Thank you!